# Bigcommerce sale price not being calculated when logged in

Tags: templates, content-management-system, bigcommerce

The ProductPrice variable is responsible for displaying the cost of the item, when a user is a guest the variable holds the sale price of the product, but when a user is logged in the sale price is not being calculated.
Hopefully somebody has encountered something similar with bigcommerce.

This is the template file:

```
<li class="%%GLOBAL_AlternateClass%%">
<div class="ProductWrapper">
    <div class="ProductImage QuickView" data-product="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductThumb%%
    </div>
    <div class="ProductDetails">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%" class="%%GLOBAL_SearchTrackClass%% pname">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>
    </div>
    <em class="p-price">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</em>
    <div class="ProductCompareButton" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideCompareItems%%">
        <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox" name="compare_product_ids" id="compare_%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%" value="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%" onclick="product_comparison_box_changed(this.checked)" /> <label for="compare_%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">%%LNG_Compare%%</label> <br />
    </div>
    <div class="ProductActionAdd" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideActionAdd%%;">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductURL%%" class="btn Small icon-%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%</a>
    </div>
</div>
</li>​
```

Comment: This is a bug in BigCommerce when you are using customer groups. If you call technical support, they can assist you with a workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have reached out to them twice without much help, I look forward to working with this new lead.

Comment: If the workaround is not too elaborate, can you give me an idea of what it involves?

Comment: The workaround requires a staff member of BC to login, or I would.

Comment: Thanks I called them and they resolved it. It was the bug you described and it was caused through conflicting API flags from an update or so ago